# Don't Show Validation Summary Message First Time MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC Identity For login and MVC Validation For Required Fields, I don't want to show error messages first time. It should be shown only when user click submit button. But as page is getting post to ActionResult every time, So it is showing me validation as well.
What is a way to not show messages first time on page load.
I have used this code to clear messages, but it clear every time

[image]

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
       return View("Login");
}
foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
{
   ModelState[key].Errors.Clear();
}
}
//Model
 public class LoginModel
{

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
   }

  //HTML
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary("")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { maxlength = "45", placeholder = "User Email" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { maxlength = "45", placeholder = "User Password" })
        <button type="submit" class="LoginBtn" id="loginButton"></button>
   }
```

Comment: Keep this style in page `.validation-summary-valid { display:none; }`

Comment: Show your GET method - you appear to have a parameter for the model (which is wrong)

Comment: I have added complete code Stephen

Comment: Rahul, i need to show validation on submit click as well. Can't use this css

Comment: @Diana in your Get action why mentioning the model as parameter?? the parameter need to pass only to Post method to check the validation..try removing the model parameter in Get method and try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the `LoginModel model` parameter from your GET method. What is happening is that the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `LoginModel` as soon as the method is called. Because you are not providing any values for the properties of `LoginModel`, they are `null` and therefore validation errors are added to `ModelState` which are then displayed in the view. Instead, your method needs to be

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
  LoginModel model = new LoginModel(); // initialize the model here
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. I have separated Get and Post Action with action filters  [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]. Thanks Stephen.